# Will my fast still count if I had thoughts on breaking it?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, practical-islam, sawm, ramadan

I was feeling extreme thirst while fasting today. I did not feel sick but I woke up only one hour before suhoor and I did not get to drink that much water. I had thoughts about breaking my fast to drink some or to drink a little and then continue fasting. I wasn't sure but after a while I was about to, and then later on I changed my mind. I asked people online about it  and when someone told me it is not a valid reason to, I decided not to and to just wait until maghrib. I am now continuing with my fast but I'm concerned if thinking this already broke it. Is my fast still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, your fast is still valid. It is a very good thing to have changed your mind. Your fast would have been invalid if you would have drank even any amount of water voluntarily.